# Button is not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick

I have a button that says Top Add that is not responding when I click on it. What it is suppossed to do is alert a variable that it just added to, but it just does nothing. This is my code:

```js
$("button#left").click(function(){
    moveLeftId[moveLeftId.length]="-=50px";
    alert(moveLeftId);
});


$("button#start").click(function(){
    alert("You clicked action!");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < moveLeftId.length; i++) {
        $("div#test").animate({
           marginLeft: moveLeftId[i]
        }, 500);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < moveTopId.length; i++) {
        $("div#test").animate({
            marginTop: moveTopId[i]
        }, 500);
    }
});
/*
$("button#top").click(function(){
    moveTopId[moveTopId.length]="+=50px";
});marginTop: moveTopId[i]*/
```

```css
#test {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #C00;
    margin-left: 500px; 
    margin-top:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" color="white">Hi</div>
<button id="left">Left add</button>
<button id="start">Action!</button>
<button id="top" onclick="moveTopId[moveTopId.length]='-=50px';
    alert(moveTopId);">Top add</button>
<script>var moveLeftId=new Array(["-=50px"]);
    var moveBottomId=new Array(["-=50px"]);</script>
```

As you see, I tried separating some of the code into other script tags, but that didn't make a difference. I don't know what I should do!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Running your code snippet above, the only button which doesn't `alert` for me is the one whose event handler is commented out (`button#top`). Am I not understanding the question?

Comment: I got an error : 

Uncaught ReferenceError: moveTopId is not defined 
Define moveTopId

Comment: @Colin I should probably edit the question. The button that says Top Add is the one that doesn't work, so you have the question right! Thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define this array so you could not get the Array.length if he is not defined.

Your script is working just need to define this variables at the start.

http://jsfiddle.net/2xybrnrz/

```
var moveLeftId = [];
var moveTopId = [];

$("button#left").click(function(){
    moveLeftId[moveLeftId.length]="-=50px";
    alert(moveLeftId);
});


$("button#start").click(function(){
    alert("You clicked action!");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < moveLeftId.length; i++) {
        $("div#test").animate({
           marginLeft: moveLeftId[i]
        }, 500);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < moveTopId.length; i++) {
        $("div#test").animate({
            marginTop: moveTopId[i]
        }, 500);
    }
});

$("button#top").click(function(){
    moveTopId[moveTopId.length]="+=50px";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("button#left").click(function(){
    moveLeftId[moveLeftId.length]="-=50px";
    alert(moveLeftId);
});


$("button#start").click(function(){
    alert("You clicked action!");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < moveLeftId.length; i++) {
        $("div#test").animate({
           marginLeft: moveLeftId[i]
        }, 500);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < moveTopId.length; i++) {
        $("div#test").animate({
            marginTop: moveTopId[i]
        }, 500);
    }
});
/*
$("button#top").click(function(){
    moveTopId[moveTopId.length]="+=50px";
});marginTop: moveTopId[i]*/
```

```css
#test {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #C00;
    margin-left: 500px; 
    margin-top:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" color="white">Hi</div>
<button id="left">Left add</button>
<button id="start">Action!</button>
<button id="top" onclick="moveTopId[moveTopId.length]='-=50px';
    alert(moveTopId);">Top add</button>
<script>var moveLeftId=new Array(["-=50px"]);
    var moveBottomId=new Array(["-=50px"]);var moveTopId =new Array(["-=50px"]);
</script>
```

Comment: I added moveTopId because it wasn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

try adding your code inside

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     //    put code here
});
```

This is because if your JS and JQuery are being ran before the page finishes loading..